# Difference between 24bit addresses and 24bit arithmetic vs 24 bit address with address arithmetic of 16 bit address?

Tags: c++, microcontroller, pointer-arithmetic

i have found in the c167 Dokumentation a note on arithmetic of pointers.
There are two macros _huge and _shuge.

A cite from the Doku:

> _huge or _shuge. Huge data may be anywhere in memory and you can
>
> also reference it using a 24 bit address. However, address arithmetic
>   is
>
> done using the complete address (24 bit). Shuge data may also be
>
> anywhere in memory and you can also reference it using a 24 bit
>   address.
>
> However, address arithmetic is done using a 16 bit address.

So what is the difference in the usage of _huge vs _shuge? 
In my understanding the arithmetic of pointers is using an offset from a start address

Example of what I understood so far:

> &a[0] + 1 where one element of a is int32 &a[0] gives me the address
>   of the first element thi
>   s would be equal to 0x1234211 + 32Bit for
>   example.**

Is there a difference considering the Note from above and what is the difference in _huge and _shuge?

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huge was used in the (good?) old 8086 family mode addressing. These were 16 bit processors with a 24 bits address bus. A full address was given by a segment (16 bits) address and an offset (again 16 bits), with the following formula:

```
linear_address = segment * 16 + offset
```

The difference between 2 `_huge` adresses was computed by first converting both to 24 bits linear addresses and substracting that value, while for `_shuge` one, segment and offset were separately substracted.

Example 0010:1236 - 0011:1234 would give 0000:0012 (18) if computed as `_huge` and `0001:0002` as `_shuge`

Comment: Hello Serge, I honestly dont understand your example: Due to your explaination I converted 0x00101236 and 0x00111234 to decimal. 1053238 - 1118772 = -65534 converting this in hex is something like FFFF FFFF FFFF 0002 in 32bit

Comment: Now i got it you mean logical address on the architecture written as segment:offset

Answer (score 1):

It's obliquely explained on the 17th page (labeled as page 7) of this PDF: https://www.tasking.com/support/c166/c166_user_guide_v4.0.pdf

> By default all __far pointer arithmetic is 14-bit. This implies that comparison of __far pointers is also
>   done in 14-bit. For __shuge the same is true, but then with 16-bit arithmetic.This saves code significantly,
>   but has the following implications:
>
> • Comparing pointers to different objects is not reliable. It is only reliable when it is known that these
>   objects are located in the same page.
>
> • Comparing with NULL is not reliable. Objects that are located in another page at offset 0x0000 have
>   the low 14 bits (the page offset) zero and will also be evaluated as NULL.

In other words, `_shuge` pointers' bits above the lowest 16 are ignored except when dereferencing them.  You may also note that `_shuge` pointers have 16-bit alignment, meaning their lowest 4 bits are always zero and therefore only 12 bits need to be considered in comparison or subtraction.

Comment: Does this mean in some strange szenario when I use a Pointer as reference to call an Object I might get a "wild pointer" since the bits above the lowest 16bit are ignored? Or is this only true for arithmetic operations? that the bits are ignored?

Comment: It's only true for arithmetic, not for dereferencing, as I mentioned.